# averaging of multiple curves for signal processing

Tags: signal-processing

I have response (vibration amplitude over frequency steps) measured over various point on  my structure.

In simpler way: i have 5 response curves(amplitude vs frequency plot) from same structure is there way to express them as average curve. i want to combine all five curve as express as one single. what methods are there in maths to do so.

**EDIT:** As seen this is vibration measurement on multiple point on structure. I am mostly interested what will be peaks when globally. so averaging this curves probably still give all the peaks at said same frequencies (amplitude doesnot matter) as individual curves.

Then I can say, the structure has global peaks at those frequencies as in averaged curves.

[image]

Comment: you may want to give more details about your question. what average curve are you talking about. why not taking the average of all 5 curves?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to "average" the response curves?  What are we trying to find out about the structure?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/we5g2h131/

Comment: you can put the image here just. Go to edit and use the icon above which appears as an image.

Comment: you can average the signals are you average the numbers. In Matlab: $V_1=V_2+V_3$, the sizes of the vectors must be the same. If the some of the signals are more important, then you may want to weight it differently before summing up.

Comment: thank you seyhmus..For Image i need more reputation points

Comment: Why not just add the functions together?

Comment: Function how? formulating function for each curve?